# How to set different lengths of animation for different objects?

Tags: animation

I have made an animation for two different objects, say a cube and sphere, and I gave different keyframes to both objects.

For example: I gave total keyframes of 30 to the cube and 50 to the sphere. The end keyframe is 50. Now, when I hit the animation, the action starts and cube remains still after 30 keyframes. However, I don't want that.

I want the cube to come back to the first frame after it has crossed 30 keyframes without waiting for the sphere of 50 keyframes to be completed.

I shared my blend file
[image]

Comment: You cannot have that. You can add a _Cycles_ modifier to the cube animation so that it repeats after finishing, but then the next cycle will be finished at frame 60, which means the sphere animation will stand still. If you repeat that, it goes to 100, so you have to make the overall length the lowest common multiple. However, what you are asking is like watching a movie, and when one character dies halfway through, the end credits should roll, while the movie moves on for the living characters. That's not possible. The _Timeline_  is the movie, cube and sphere are the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Select the Cube's keyframe in the timeline at frame 1 and Ctrl-D to duplicate it. Then drag it to frame 50 and run the animation to see if that does what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank You But my question is how to apply different timeline length to different objects in same file?

Comment: I don't really understand that. The timeline is the same length for all the objects in your scene. You can't have different timeline lengths for each object. If you want the cube to jump back to its rest position after frame 30, just drag the last keyframe back from frame 50 to frame 30.

Comment: I reckon you can sort-of do that with the NLA editor but that'd be more complex than just duplicating a keyframe.

Comment: @L0Lock Yes I suppose you could, but like you I can't really see the point to be honest.